# Not able to display desired result in text view, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, textview, location, coordinates

I am trying to make an app that captures the last location coordinates and displays them in the text view. I have done it successfully in the emulator. However, while testing the app on mobile, it shows the default text that I wrote in the text view instead of the captured coordinates.

Here is the Java code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
LocationManager locationManager;
Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mContext = this;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            2000,
            10, locationListenerGPS);
    isLocationEnabled();

}

LocationListener locationListenerGPS=new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
        double latitude=location.getLatitude();
        double longitude=location.getLongitude();
        String msg="Latitude: "+latitude + "\nLongitude: "+longitude;
        TextView stc;. //TextView for the location.
        stc = findViewById(R.id.stc);
        stc.setText(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
};


protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    isLocationEnabled();
}

private void isLocationEnabled() {

    if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Enable Location");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Your locations setting is not enabled. Please enabled it in settings menu.");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert=alertDialog.create();
        alert.show();
    }
    else{
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Location");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Coordinates captured");
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert=alertDialog.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

}

I have asked for the following permissions in the Manifest file.

ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, INTERNET and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add for access permission and once user gives access then try to get user location.

This has to be like this since Android 6.0

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java

Comment: I will try it and see if it works or not...But, why is it that the Application is running well in emulator and not in actual mobile? On the start it does ask for permission.